# What is topology of $X^{\mathbb{Z}}$ where $X$ is a topological space.

Tags: general-topology, products

Let $(X, \tau)$ be a topological space and $I$ be an infinite set. I want to define a topology on $X^I$ by open sets in $X$. Is it true that a non-empty set $\mathcal{U}\subseteq X^I$ is open in $X^I$ if there is finite set $A$ such that $\mathcal{U}=\prod_{\alpha\in A} U_\alpha$, where $U_\alpha=X$ if $\alpha\notin A$ and for $\alpha\in A$, $U_\alpha\in \tau$.`

Please help me to know is it true?

Comment: What you've defined is merely the standard *base* that will induce the product topology, which is by far the most commonly chosen topology on that set $X^{\Bbb Z}$.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma, In my research, I need to have $\mathcal{U}_A$ as basis sets, where $A$ is finite and $\mathcal{U}_A=\prod_{\alpha\in A} U_\alpha$ and $U_\alpha=X$ for $\alpha\notin A$ and $U_\alpha\in\tau$ if $\alpha\in A$.

Comment: So exactly the base sets you described. No problem right? But all open sets are unions of the $\mathcal{U}_A$.

Answer (score 1):

There are all kinds of topologies on $X^{I}$. The collection of sets you have defined is not a topology. You have to all possible unions of those sets to get a  topology. The resulting topology is called the product topology on $X^{I}$. [For  another topology you can look at Wikipedia for the 'box topology']